# Geopandas: How to specify data type when save it as csv?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I read a geopandas

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('../US/county/myShape.shp')
gdf.head()

    COUNTYNS    geometry
0   01026336    POLYGON ((-78.90200 34.83527, -78.79960 34.850...
1   01025844    POLYGON ((-80.49737 35.20210, -80.29542 35.502...
2   01074088    POLYGON ((-81.68699 41.13596, -81.68495 41.277...
3   01213687    POLYGON ((-76.81373 41.59003, -76.22014 41.541...
4   01384015    POLYGON ((-95.15274 32.66095, -95.15211 32.902...
```

If I save it as `.csv` and load it again I have:

```
gdf.to_file('../US/county/continental.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('../US/county/continental.csv')
df.head()
    COUNTYNS    geometry
0   1026336     POLYGON ((-78.90199799999999 34.835268, -78.79...
1   1025844     POLYGON ((-80.49737499999999 35.202104, -80.29...
2   1074088     POLYGON ((-81.68698999999999 41.135956, -81.68...
3   1213687     POLYGON ((-76.81373099999999 41.590034, -76.22...
4   1384015     POLYGON ((-95.15273999999999 32.660949, -95.15...
```

How can I keep the right format as `string` for `COUNTYNS` when I save it?

Comment: it seems that it saves  `COUNTYNS` as integer and not as string

Comment: sorry, is necessary `dtype = str` parameter like `dtype={' COUNTYNS': str}`